# Column 'desconto' cannot be resolved. Como usar uma coluna que é resultado de um calculo para calcular outra coluna na mesma query?

Tags: sql

Tenho a seguinte query:

```
Select price, col2, col3*7.5 AS desconto, (price*desconto) AS finalprice
From tab1.
```

Quando executo recebo a seguinte mensagem: `Column 'desconto' cannot be resolved`.

Como resolver esse erro?

Nota:
Estou rodando AWS [Athena que segue o mesmo padrão SQL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/athena/latest/ug/what-is.html).

Comment: Já pensou em usar uma CTE ( http://www.macoratti.net/13/05/sql_cte1.htm ) para tratar as colunas antes de utilizar?

Comment: Qual o `SGBD` utilizado?

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 2):

Baseando-se na sua Query, não é melhor fazer da forma abaixo?

```
Select price, col2, col3*7.5 AS desconto, (price*(col3*7.5)) AS finalprice
From tab1.
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção é utilizar uma `subquery` no `FROM`:

```
SELECT x.*,
       x.price * x.desconto AS finalprice
  FROM (
    SELECT price,
           col2,
           col3 * 7.5 AS desconto
      FROM tab1
  ) x
```